# Why would a single task executor stop processing tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading

We're using a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` that we obtained by calling `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`. This `ExecutorService` can sometimes stop processing tasks, even though it has not been shutdown and continues to accept new tasks without throwing exceptions.

Yes, it's nearly a verbatim duplicate of [this historical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344788/what-would-make-a-single-task-executor-stop-processing-tasks), but the ideas proposed there do not solve our problem, hence the duplication.

The accepted answer proposes these three approaches:

> You're over-feeding the work queue. You can't just keep stuffing
> new tasks into the queue, with no regard for the consumption rate of
> the task executors. You need to figure out some logic for knowing when
> you to block new additions to the work queue.

No, we're not over-feeding the work queue. We added some control code and we have proof that the work queue is no greater than 10 when the problem happens. We have logic on our code to block new additions.

> Any uncaught exception in a task's thread can completely kill the
> thread. When that happens, the ExecutorService spins up a new thread
> to replace it. But that doesn't mean you can ignore whatever problem
> is causing the thread to die in the first place! Find those uncaught
> exceptions and catch them!

As far as we can tell, there are no uncaught exceptions. First, the `Thread` we pass to the `ExecutorService` is configured properly with a call to `setUncaughtExceptionHandler`. Second, the runnable we pass to the `ExecutorService` is properly try-catch'ed:

```
executor.execute(
    new Runnable() {
        try {
            // our code goes here
        } catch ( Exception exception ) {
            // log exception
        }
    }
);
```

> You might have a rare deadlock between your task threads. Most of the
> time, you get lucky, and the deadlock doesn't manifest itself. But
> occasionally, two or more of your task threads get into a state where
> they're waiting for the release of a lock held by the other thread.

This does not seem to be the case. We added some log messages and every `Runnable` finishes properly. What happens is that the next one is not started.

We are able to identify that the queue is not being consumed.
When it happens, we check for `executor.isShutdown()` (returns `false`), `executor.isTerminated()` (returns `false`) and  `thread.isAlive()` (returns `true`).

Comment: What java version and what JVM are you using?

Comment: What version of Java?  And which vendor for the JVM?  What I can think of: you have caught an exception and thrown the error away, preventing you from seeing the problem.  Threads really aren't "done" as a result, and your logs might not be correct.  We'd basically need code that reproduces the problem, which we don't have.

Comment: @pringi We're using Oracle JRE 1.8.0_191-b12

Comment: Get the stack trace of the VM to verify that your Runnable is not stuck - do this using one of `jstack {vmpid}`, CTRL-BREAK in VM's console, or `kill -QUIT {vmpid}` from another terminal.

Comment: Can you also check the result of thread.isInterrupted()? Also could you at least go to version 202 of JRE 1.8?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I'm going to check them out.